# after connecting db,i can read the csv file and pass those values and i can run this jsr223 sampler,it shown below errors,please correct below code

Tags: mysql, groovy

import groovy.sql.Sql  def url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automation1' def u . . . '' Encountered "def" at line 3, column 1.  in inline evaluation of: import groovy.sql.Sql def url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automation1' def u . . . '' at line number 3 javax.script.ScriptException: In file: inline evaluation of: import groovy.sql.Sql  def url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automation1' def u . . . '' Encountered "def" at line 3, column 1.  in inline evaluation of: import groovy.sql.Sql def url = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/automation1' def u . . . '' at line number 3 at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:82)

error coming i run the jsr223 sampler,what is the problem and please give me solution

Answer (score 0):

You're using [Beanshell](http://www.beanshell.org/) language and [`def` is a Groovy keyword](https://www.baeldung.com/groovy-def-keyword) so make sure to choose `groovy` as the language for the JSR223 Sampler and at least this error will go away.

Please avoid using Beanshell, [Groovy is the recommended scripting option since JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/is-beanshell-dead/)